# Classical navigation properties vs owned types in aggregates

Tags: entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design, ef-core-2.2

After release of `EF Core 2.2` it is now possible to have both single and collection values of owned types.

In contrast to classical navigational properties owned types are always included in the entity, so owned types looks like a natural way of describing the shape of an aggregate.

*Are there any DDD related use cases where classical navigation properties are still better?*

Update 1

Prior to 2.2 I was able to call [`modelBuilder.Entity<OwnedType>`](https://michaelscodingspot.com/2018/12/04/c-features-innovations-or-imitations-part-3/) and configure alternative key.
Now with `2.2` I started getting errors during migration: `primary key is not defined for the entity`. However, `ReferenceOwnershipBuilder` class which is passed as a parameter to `buildAction` lambda in method `OwnsOne` does not contain `HasAlternateKey`. This is currently a [known limitation](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11336).

Update 2
Currently owned types do not support inheritance. This may be critical for some use cases.

Comment: IMHO the question "Are there any DDD related use cases where classical navigation properties are still better" is misplaced, because a navigation property is an infrastructure concern, an implementation detail, while DDD is concerned with the Domain Model. Any persistence mechanism can potentially work for your solution, but your persistence model is NOT your domain model, and whether you choose navigation properties over owned types or otherwise is a decision to be made when optimizing your storage according to your data access patterns.